# Looking for the name of a graphic novel, scifi, read in mid 80s

Tags: story-identification, comics, novel

I remember reading a graphic novel around the same time frame *Elfquest* was published. There was a new experimental ship that was stolen/hijacked, that when it went into FTL space was white and stars were black. About anything else I remember was an Earth officer, relieving a bridge officer for a break, then convincing the ship to crash itself into a planetary headquarters. 
That's all I can remember, would like to find it again.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: So, around 1978? That's when Elfquest was first published.

Comment: I recall reading a story with white space and black stars as well... cannot recall any more than that though.

Comment: I have this book.  The guy had a psychic pet that looked like a monkey.  I will update when I find it.

Answer (score 6):

This is [*Lightrunner*](http://www.comicsreview.co.uk/nowreadthis/2010/05/29/lightrunner/).  Not a very good story but it was interesting when I was a kid.  It was published in the correct time frame and involves the theft of an experimental ship.  The story concludes with the scene described in the OP about the ship being scuttled into a bunch of other experimental ships.

> In the future, capitalism runs the universe in the form of planetary Corprostates held together by a web of trade undertaken by tachyon-driven solar sailing ships plying the perilous routes of the “Star Stream”. The Empyrean Alliance is a tenuous association of Free States, restive, politically insecure and greatly dependent on the trustworthy valour of the apolitical Empyrforce – a Navy-style peacekeeping/police militia.
>
> The tale begins with young Burne Garrett, son of a legendary Empyrforce hero, who failed to make the grade and scrubbed out of his military training. Garrett is a pathetic disappointment to himself and everybody else. Now a lowly PR hack he is filming the initial tests of a radical new type of faster than light starship – The Stream Breaker – when calamity comes calling.
>
> The new super-vessel suddenly comes to eerie life and takes off with him aboard, vanishing into the unknown, and the unwitting fool is suddenly Public Enemy #1! Framed, lost and desperate Garrett is soon plunged deep into the seedy underbelly of civilisation, a pawn of pirates and raiders until he is adopted by the spoiled, rich wild-child Lanie of Abul Sara (think Paris Hilton in lace-up high heel thigh-boots with a ray-gun… and now stop thinking of that because that’s not how she looks but what she’s like…).

[image: Graphic novel cover to "Lightrunner"]

[image: The Star Stream]

It was published in 1983 by The Donning Company Publishers, who also put out a [book collecting the first chapters](http://elfquest.wikia.com/wiki/Donning_Starblaze,_Elfquest_Book_1) of *Elfquest*.

Comment: Does it match the OP's description?

Comment: @SDH: I added another image showing the "Star Stream" and providing information about the publishers and their tie to Elfquest.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Matches exactly.